# to lease property vs to rent / rent out property exact meanings

Tags: word-meaning

Explain, please, where I am mistaken:
a) "to rent" is you take or use timely smb's thing or property for money.
b) "to rent out" is you give to smb your own thing or property for money.

1st question: to rent property is to lend thing or to borrow (timely for money)?
 2nd question: to lease = "to rent" and to lease out = "to rent out" as described in "a" and "b"?

Answer (score 2):

**To rent** can be something a landlord does or a tenant.

> He rented his cottage to a young couple.
>
> A young couple rented his cottage.

To **rent out** is something only a landlord can do.

Renting is by definition not *gratis*.  Lending is gratis.

**lease**, like rent, is also bidirectional, to acquire use of something, or to grant use of something, in exchange for some valuable form of consideration, usually money.

The lessor **leases {something} out**.

Answer (score 1):

**rent a property** and **lease a property** basically mean the same thing.

When you rent an apartment, there is a contract called A Lease or Rental Agreement.

Let's look out the two parties (the tenant and landlord OR the lessee and lessor or the owner and tenant)

If I own property, I can rent it out or rent it. Both are fine. So, is lease or lease out. They mean the same thing.

Here's the tricky bit: Although **I can say that I'm renting (or leasing) out my apartment** [to you] or **renting (or leasing) my apartment [to you**], **what does not work** is for you to say to me or someone else about my property anything other than**: I am renting or leasing her property. No out. BUT: She is renting out the apartment to me. The **out** always goes with the owner or the owner's representative: I am renting out her apartment means: I'm managing the rental for her.

So, yes, unless you know the parties and who owns what, **there can be ambiguity in the simple sentence**: "I'm renting the apartment" because it can mean one of two things: "I'm renting the apartment to you" or "I'm renting apartment from you."

But the **out** makes it clear: I'm renting out her apartment. = I'm doing it for her.
I'm renting out my apartment. I'm taking my property and renting it to a tenant.